# Область видимости фунции, возврат (?)

Tags: javascript, область-видимости, return

Пытаюсь в первой фунции(внешней) использовать(push в results, return) результаты из второй(внутренней). Нужно записть в results массив arr и сумму sum. Не получается - записывается пустой массив и 0, хотя в возврате оно есть, вроде печатается значение, но как его использовать?

```
    function func(limit) {
          let results = [];
          let arr = [];
          console log(limit);
          function fn() {
            let sum = 0;
            for (let i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
              sum += arguments[i];
              arr.push(arguments[i]);
            };
            console.log(arr);
            results.push({args: arr, result: sum});
            return sum;
          };
          fn();
          console.log(results);
          return fn;
        };

        const mSum = func(2);
        console.log(mSum(3, 4, 5));
```

Comment: Какой результат ожидается?

Comment: сумма 3,4,5 = 12. Но мне дальше надо работать  с массиво results и туда надо запушить эти значения

Comment: Что-то уже было [подобное](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/985620/256824)

Answer (score 0):

Вы обращаетесь к аргументам другой функции, которую запускаете без аргументов. Как вариант запишите аргументы в переменную:

```js
function func(limit) {
      let results = [];
      let arr = [];
      let arg = arguments;
      function fn() {
        let sum = 0;
        for (let i = 0; i < arg.length; i++) {
          sum += arg[i];
          arr.push(arg[i]);
        };
        results.push({args: arr, result: sum});
        return sum;
      };
      return fn();
    };
    
    
console.log(func("test1","test2","test3"));
```

Comment: отредактировал в первом сообщении. Аргументы во внутреннюю фунцию я передаб дальше. Попробовал присвоить arguments в переменную, только внутри внутренней фунции fn, результат такой же, как и был

Comment: @ma_le похоже я не до конца понимаю в чем именно у вас проблема, но в любом случае arguments во внутренней функции будет другой.

Answer (score 0):

```
function func(...limit) {
  let results = [];
  let arr = [];
  console.log(limit);
  function fn() {
    let sum = 0;
    for (let i = 0; i < limit.length; i++) {
      sum += limit[i];
      arr.push(limit[i]);
    };
    console.log(arr);
    results.push({args: arr, result: sum});
    return results;

  };
  console.log(results);
  return fn;
};

var f = func(10, 11, 12);
f();
```

Если честно, не совсем понял суть вопроса. Непонятно, что вы подразумеваете под arguments

Comment: arguments это аргументы внутренней фунции, которые я передаю нижеconst mSum  = func(2);
        console.log(mSum(3, 4, 5));

Comment: Мне просто аргумент limit тоже понадобится дальше во внешней фунции, и надо передать аргументы во внутреннюю, как показано

Comment: Запустил ваш исправленный код. Вроде же всё работает, как вы хотите

Comment: да, на выходе выдает 12, что мне и надо, но мне еще надо передать массив arr и переменную sum объектом в массив results, который находится в функции func. если написать console.log(arr, sum) внутри функции внутренней fn, то все ок - они там, посчитанные, но когда я их пушу в results, то пушатся пустой массив и 0, вот не могу поняттьь, почему

Comment: Из своего кода просто убрать "fn()"

Comment: так идет пуш в массив results, передаются ключи args и result, но значения пустые. Если убрать, как предлагаете, то вообще ничгео не пушит